# Jenkins running Cypress test ends up with timeout

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, cypress

I installed Jenkins in a Linux server (I've not a docker container, just a regular server). I installed all suggested plugins in order to automate stuff for a Java and Angular applications.

Right now I've a problem running [cypress tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Setting-up-CI). I can build Angular application, but I'm facing problems running cypress test in headless mode.

I created a "Freestyle project" (not a pipeline), just to run tests.

[image]

This is the relevant script section in my Angular project:

```
"scripts": {   
    "build": "ng build",
    "start": "ng serve --port 3030",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

As stated [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Solutions), running the script test it should work and cypress should wait the application to be up and running.

When I run the Jenkins build, however, I've this error:

```
    npm install
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

> websocket@1.0.31 install /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/websocket
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/websocket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/websocket/build'

> node-sass@4.13.1 install /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/node-sass/4.13.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> @angular/cli@9.1.1 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js


> cypress@4.3.0 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/cypress
> node index.js --exec install


Cypress 4.3.0 is installed in /var/lib/jenkins/.cache/Cypress/4.3.0


> ngx-infinite-scroll@8.0.1 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/ngx-infinite-scroll
> opencollective-postinstall || exit 0

[96m[1mThank you for using ngx-infinite-scroll![96m[1m
[0m[96mIf you rely on this package, please consider supporting our open collective:[22m[39m
> [94mhttps://opencollective.com/ngx-infinite-scroll/donate[0m


> node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.

added 1799 packages from 1690 contributors and audited 20778 packages in 73.931s

51 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
+ npm run test

> test@0.0.6-b04032020 test /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test
> start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run

starting server using command "npm run start"
and when url "[ 'http://localhost:3030' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "npm run cy:run"

> test@0.0.6-b04032020 start /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test
> ng serve --port 3030

WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
case.
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dom : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/api : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/utils : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputtext : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dropdown : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/focustrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/messages : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/progressbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-server : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-translate/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-highlightjs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/blockui : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/breadcrumb : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/calendar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/captcha : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/carousel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/chart : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/codehighlighter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/colorpicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/confirmdialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/contextmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dataview : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/defer : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dragdrop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dynamicdialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/editor : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fieldset : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fileupload : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/fullcalendar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/galleria : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/gmap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inplace : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputmask : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputswitch : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/inputtextarea : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/keyfilter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/lightbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/listbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/megamenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/menubar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/message : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/multiselect : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/orderlist : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/organizationchart : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/overlaypanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panelmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/password : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/picklist : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/progressspinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/radiobutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/rating : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/scrollpanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/selectbutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/sidebar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/slidemenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/splitbutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/steps : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tabmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tabview : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/terminal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tieredmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/toast : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/togglebutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/treetable : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/tristatecheckbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/virtualscroller : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/bottom-sheet : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material-moment-adapter : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-server/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/service-worker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/service-worker/config : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @auth0/angular-jwt : module as esm5
Compiling @fullcalendar/angular : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ngx-translate/http-loader : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling angularx-qrcode : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling material-community-components : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ng-lazyload-image : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ng2-ckeditor : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ng2-tel-input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-barcode6 : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-cookie-service : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-daterangepicker-material : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-device-detector : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-highlightjs/plus : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-image-zoom : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-infinite-scroll : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-loading : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Timeout
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/wait-on/lib/wait-on.js:145:74)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at AsyncAction.dispatch [as work] (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/observable/timer.js:31:16)
    at AsyncAction._execute (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js:71:18)
    at AsyncAction.execute (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncAction.js:59:26)
    at AsyncScheduler.flush (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/rxjs/internal/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js:52:32)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.0.6-b04032020 test: `start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.0.6-b04032020 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2020-04-09T11_06_30_762Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

and this is the verbose log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/opt/local/node/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/local/node/12/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle test@0.0.6~pretest: test@0.0.6
6 info lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: test@0.0.6
7 verbose lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: PATH: /opt/local/node/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test/node_modules/.bin:/opt/local/node/12/bin:/opt/local/java/8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: CWD: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test
10 silly lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: Args: [ '-c', 'start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run' ]
11 silly lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test@0.0.6~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: test@0.0.6 test: `start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/local/node/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/local/node/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid test@0.0.6
15 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular test
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-96-generic
17 verbose argv "/opt/local/node/node-v12.16.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/local/node/12/bin/npm" "run" "test"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error test@0.0.6 test: `start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3030 cy:run`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test@0.0.6 test script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Do you have any hint?

Comment: We are running into the same issue with `run-p` `ng serve` and `wait on` after upgrading to Angular 9. In Angular 8 it is working fine.

Comment: Additional info: we are not using Jenkins but Azure Devops Pipelines.

Comment: Did any of you find a solution? Running into the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

While it's not obvious from the error message, it seems that you are hitting the the [timeout](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test#timeout) for `start-server-and-test`. Since starting your server appears to include a compilation step it might take some time. You can increase the timeout (default 5 min) by setting the environment variable `WAITON_TIMEOUT` to the desired timeout in milliseconds. Alternatively, you could make a static build and serve it by something else than the devserver. For example an express server.

Answer (score 0):

Now WAITON_TIMEOUT has changed to WAIT_ON_INTERVAL.